# Possible to build contribution report that groups contributions by employer and includes number of employees?

Tags: civireport, relationships, reports, custom-reports

I would love to be able to make a report in Civi using stock reports, extended reports or reports pro that produces or can be modified to generage the following output:

| Employer | # of Employees | # of Employees that Donated | Participation Rate | # of Contributions | Average Contribution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple Corp | 100 | 7 | 7% | 9 | $45 |
| Orange Corp | 32 | 7 | 22% | 9 | $95 |

"# of employees" = Number of employees in system with that employer listed

So far i have been able to get the following:

| Employer | # of Contributions | Average Contribution |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple Corp | 9 | $45 |
| Orange Corp | 9 | $95 |

but that's the end of my progress. I also notice that if I choose to filter by tag, it uses the contributors tag and not the employer's tag :-/ I am also open to two reports that I can export into excel to generate the report I want.

Thanks all!

Edit: Sorry the second table shows up in preview, but then breaks in actual post. Civi 5.40 D7

Comment: I haven't used the new SearchKit yet, it may be one option. If this were Drupal I would presume I could build this via Views (if necessary using views_field_view to bring the data in to one table)

Comment: I will check out searchkit and see what I can do in views - thanks!